# I want to run spark shell in client mode?

Tags: apache-spark

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1519491124804_0002).
```

I need master = yarn-client

error:

```
Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties Setting default log level to "WARN". 
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel). 
18/02/24 22:27:29 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
18/02/24 22:27:29 WARN Utils: Your hostname, suraj resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.43.193 instead (on interface wlan0) 
18/02/24 22:27:29 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address 
18/02/24 22:27:32 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME. 
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.43.193:4040 Spark context available as 'sc' (master
= yarn, app id = application_1519491124804_0002). 
Spark session available as 'spark'. 
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/    
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1
      /_/
          Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161) Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information.
```

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is?

Comment: There is no error here.

Answer (score 2):

> I need master = yarn-client

In Spark 2.x `master = yarn-client` is deprecated.

`spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client` is the correct way to run the shell

The default deploy-mode is `client`

Comment: I install in my pc . in stand alone mode still it work?

Comment: Standalone mode runs only there, not in YARN. If you have YARN configured, then yes it'll work with YARN client mode... There is no error in your question, so what's the problem?